# amMap remove home button control

Tags: javascript, ammap

I am trying to remove all the controls from amMap. I have successfully removed the zoom controls. Is it possible to remove the home button also, I cant find it anywhere?

```
"zoomControl": {
  "zoomControlEnabled": false,
  "panControlEnabled": false,
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. I missed it in the documentation.

```
"zoomControl": {
    "homeButtonEnabled": false,
    "zoomControlEnabled": false,
    "panControlEnabled": false,
},
```